# Finding probability when two dice are rolled

Tags: probability, dice

> You have two dice. Die one is a standard die with the six faces marked from 1 to 6. The second die has two faces marked with 1, two faces marked with 2 and two faces marked with 3. Both dice are rolled. The probability that
>   the sum of values on the top face of the two dice is greater than 6 is:
>
> A. 6/36
>
> B. 8/36
>
> C. 10/36
>
> D. 12/36

Comment: "Die $2$ has $2$ faces each marked with $1,2,3$"... Can you explain? A die cannot have two faces. A coin *has* 2 faces. And what do you mean by each face is marked by $1,2,3$. Also, welcome to MSE!!! To get a good response please include your our thoughts ;otherwise no one will bother to asnwer and you question will be closed. This is not a homework help site.;-)

Comment: @tatan The not standard die has 6 faces: {1,1,2,2,3,3}

Comment: @DanielMathias She wrote in the question "two faces"... isn't it?

Comment: @tatan Two faces marked 1, two faces marked 2, two faces marked 3

Comment: @DanielMathias Okay... I see... lack of punctuations is making it hard to follow the English... Please go on and edit the question and add proper punctuations

Comment: @tatan i edited the question.. hope now you can understand it. sorry for inconvenience

Comment: @DanielMathias thank you for correcting it. and also for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel Mathias already added a good asnwer but I am posting my asnwer since I already began writing it-
$$\text{First Die(Left)-SecondDie(Right)}$$
$$6-\{1,1,2,2,3,3\}$$
$$5-\{2,2,3,3\}$$
$$4-\{3,3\}$$

So $$P(Sum>6)=(\frac16\times1)+(\frac16\times\frac46)+(\frac16\times\frac26)=\frac{12}{36}$$

Comment: That should be $\frac{12}{36}$

Comment: it should be 12/36

Comment: I think I should revise class 1 addition once more ;-P @MinaxiJoshi

Comment: @DanielMathias Edited ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Make a table of possible outcomes:
\begin{array}{c|cc}
&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&\boxed7\\
1&2&3&4&5&6&\boxed7\\
2&3&4&5&6&\boxed7&\boxed8\\
2&3&4&5&6&\boxed7&\boxed8\\
3&4&5&6&\boxed7&\boxed8&\boxed9\\
3&4&5&6&\boxed7&\boxed8&\boxed9\\
\end{array}
Count the number of outcomes with sum greater than $6$. (There are $12$ of them, as marked)

The probability is therefore $\frac{12}{36}$

Comment: (+1) for creating the wonderful visual ;-)